# Error using migrate go-lang in docker "wsarecv: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."

Tags: docker, golang-migrate

Context: trying to use migrate to push tables into a docker container running postgres. I can connect to the database via my go server (same string) but not with migrate. This is the command and error message (I'm on a windows machine).

```
migrate -path db/migrations -database "postgresql://root:password@localhost:5433/post-db?ssl=disable" -verbose up
2024/01/19 19:27:40 error: read tcp [::1]:55018->[::1]:5433: wsarecv: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

.

I have disabled windows defender and the same issue still occurs. Please help